# Delete property from object failed in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have to send my jwt but I don't want to include the password property. I did `delete result.password`, but I'm still seeing the password is there. I tried `result.password = ''` I can see the password is altered, why delete doesn't work here?

```
  User.comparePassword(password, user.password , (err, result) => {
            if(result === true){
              User.getUserById(user._id, (err,result) => {

                delete result.password

                console.log(result)


                const secret = config.secret;
                const token = jwt.encode(result, secret);


                res.json({success: true, msg: token});

              });


            }else{
              res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error, Incorrect password!'});
            }
          });
```

Comment: It should work.

Comment: the only way I can see this happening is if, for example, the result passed in from `getUserById` has been "sealed" - [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) - one way around it is to use JSON methods - `result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));` as the first line in the callback should do it

Comment: Try some module like lodash omit function

Comment: Can you update the code so show how you tested modifying the password?

Answer (score 0):

The result object may have been frozen with a call to `Object.freeze( result )`. You can confirm that using `Object.isFrozen( result ) === true`. Alternatively, `delete result.password` will return `true` if the property can be deleted, `false` otherwise.

Comment: If the object were frozen, then `result.password = ''` would resolve to nothing. Oh... oops! This is a comment.

Comment: Properties of frozen objects cannot be changed..., so?

Comment: So what I'm suggesting is happening in the OP's code is: (1) `User.getUserById` reads the user object e.g. from the database (2) the result is passed to `Object.freeze` before being passed to the callback. (3) OPs code calls `delete result.password`, which fails because the object is frozen. That completely answers the OP's question - "why delete doesn't work here?"

Comment: Re-read: `"I can see the password is altered, why delete doesn't work here?"`. The result object won't have been frozen (otherwise new values could be put to its properties).

Comment: I did read it, that's why I asked the OP to clarify how he tested setting the password - he has two `result` objects in scope, so he might have tested using the wrong one. He can also try the tests I suggest in my answer, and easily confirm whether or not the object is frozen.

Comment: So this is a comment.

Comment: It's an answer as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: No. It's a suggestion.

Comment: The OP can easily confirm if it's the correct answer or not.

Comment: OP, or "O.P. (Original Post)'s author"